# why don't work useEffect when change element in []

Tags: reactjs

I want to set state when URL changes. To work with URL, I am using `useHistory`.

I have a function that would change URL like

```
var history = useHistory();
const onClickItem = list => {
  history.push('/lists/' + String(list.id));
  console.log(history.location.pathname);
};
```

and `useEffect` that would set state like

```
useEffect(() => {
  const listId = history.location.pathname.split('lists/')[1];
  if (DBList) {
    const selectList = DBList.find(list => list.id === Number(listId));
    setCelectTask(selectList);
  }
}, [history.location.pathname]);
```

In both console and URL, I see change but `useEffect` doesn't work.
I tried adding `[history, history.location]` in array but it didn't help.

Thanks.

Comment: is this component still mounted on the new url ?

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov history object from react-router should never be assigned directly, you will just loose the reference to the history object itself (history is not an Array, that push method is the one from react-router)

Comment: @Apolo, I understand you question?

Comment: If the component (where you declare useEffect) is not displayed (mounted) at the new url, the useEffect won't be called

Comment: @Apolo, this `useEffect` i use in main component and this component  displayed

Comment: I dont why, but when I add `useLocation` `useEffect` begin work.

Comment: then use location from useLocation instead of history.location.*